# zxing library on ipad could not recognize barcodes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, zxing

I'm developing two separate projects (for iphone and ipad). Device camera scans barcodes using `zxing` library and populates their text to `UILabel`. On iPhone everything is working normally but on ipad zxing can't recognize barcodes.
this is my launch code:

```
-(IBAction)scanWithCameraButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"scanWithCameraButtonPressed: called");


    ZXingWidgetController *widController = [[ZXingWidgetController alloc] initWithDelegate:self showCancel:YES OneDMode:NO];

    NSMutableSet *readers = [[NSMutableSet alloc ] init];

    //QRCodeReader* qrcodeReader = [[QRCodeReader alloc] init];
    //[readers addObject:qrcodeReader];

    //AztecReader *aztecReader = [[AztecReader alloc] init];
    //[readers addObject:aztecReader];

    //DataMatrixReader *dataMatrixReader=[[DataMatrixReader alloc] init];
    //[readers addObject:dataMatrixReader];

    //MultiFormatOneDReader *multiFormatOneDReader=[[MultiFormatOneDReader alloc] init];
    //[readers addObject:multiFormatOneDReader];

    MultiFormatUPCEANReader *multiFormatUPCEANReader=[[MultiFormatUPCEANReader alloc] init];
    [readers addObject:multiFormatUPCEANReader];


    widController.readers = readers;

    NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    widController.soundToPlay =
    [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[mainBundle pathForResource:@"beep-beep" ofType:@"aiff"] isDirectory:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:widController animated:YES];
}
```

I'm testing theese applications
on iphone 3gs with iOS 5.0 <- works
on ipad2 with iOS 5.1 <- can not recognize

all the zxing linking process was the same, code is the same.

Help me please, where the problem is?